# Mindmap tikz arrow doesn't reach the node

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

With the below code, I get the following result

```
\documentclass[convert,border=2mm,10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,mindmap}



\begin{document}
\Large

    \begin{tikzpicture}[thin,rounded corners]
    \node (A1) {$x$};
    \node (A2) [minimum size=0pt,above right=-4.5mm of A1] {\scriptsize $n$};
    \node (A4) [shape=circle,draw,fill=violet!10,align=center,above=1mm of A2,scale=0.20,thin] {-$1$} edge [->,scale=0.2] (A2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I need this arrow to be closer to *n*, something like this:

[image]

How could I get a similar result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to do it by tikz, or are other solutions ok?

Comment: I'm pretty more familiar to tikz and stuff. But, this might be a chance to learn a new process. So, go on

Comment: Which of the many libraries do you really need for this example? Please remove, what’s not needed here.

Comment: Actually I just need two of them. Just removed the rest.

Comment: Fine. Actually it looks like no mindmap feature is used here.

Answer (score 7):

If you add a `draw=red` to the node `A2`, you can see what's happening:

[image: showing the bounding box]

This is the effect of the `inner sep` of the node (maybe you confused that with `minimum size`?).

```latex
\documentclass[convert,border=2mm,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,mindmap}
\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{tikzpicture}[thin,rounded corners]
    \node (A1) {$x$};
    \node (A2) [above right=-2.5 mm of A1, inner sep=0pt] {\scriptsize $n$};
    \node (A4) [shape=circle,draw,fill=violet!10,align=center,above=2mm of A2,scale=0.20,thin] {-$1$} edge [->,scale=0.2] (A2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the snippet above]

But... are you sure you want to do this? [Using `tikzmark`](https://texdoc.org/serve/tikzmark/0) (and let LaTeX build the formula, which is a thing it does pretty well) would be a bit better... for example

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\Large
\[
    x^{\tikzmarknode[inner sep=1pt]{myn}{n}}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [<-] (pic cs:myn) ++(0, 0.2) -- ++(0,.5)
        node[shape=circle,draw,fill=violet!10, scale=0.2]{$-1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

it still requires *ad-hoc* adjustment of the distances, and the `tikz` is an overlay so you have to be careful with creating space, but...

[image: output with tikzmark]